# How to let Wordpress search result jump to that result on specific page

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am trying to create a search function on Wordpress (using elementor as theme and page builder). When the user search a word on the site and a list of results is returned. This is working fine currently, what I need is when a user clicks on the result of that search and the browser redirects to that page, the page needs to scroll to that result of the search.
(currently using ivory search plugin for the search functionality)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way you can use page permalink to goto specific page, or if its on the same page use ID to scroll to specific div/section